# Core is not generated while running with valgrind

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, valgrind

I am using valgrind (valgrind-3.10.1) on my ubuntu for testing an cpp application.
I added some code which caused the application to crash and to generate a core file, which is working perfectly fine. 
But when I run the same application with valgrind, it fails to generate a core file.

Possible fixes which i tried and not helpful.

1. Verified the core file size using ulimit -a (it is unlimited)
2. Verified the kernel.core_pattern (kernel.core_pattern =
   |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P).

What other explanation could there be for this issue?

Comment: Options i used for valgrind is "valgrind --tool=memcheck --log-file=/home/test/logs/valgrind_logs --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./testApplication"

Answer (score 1):

> But when I run the same application with valgrind, it fails to generate a core file.

Valgrind runs your application on a "virtual" CPU. When it detects that the app perform undefined operation that would normally cause the process to be terminated, it prints a message to this effect, and `exit`s.

If `ulimit -c` allows it, and the current directory is writable, Valgrind *also* produces `vgcore.$pid`, which is the memory dump in core dump format of the *simulated* application. *That* is the core file you want to analyze with GDB.

The *actual* operation that would have caused the core dump never executes on the real CPU, so the *Linux kernel* never sees the application crash.

Even if Valgrind did execute that operation and the kernel core dump was produced, that core would be useless, because it would represent the state of the Valgrind itself, not the state of the application.